# is firebase remote config api key is public or secret ? what one can do with that api key?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am security researcher and come up with one request where company is sending below request to firebase remote config ,

```
POST /v1/projects/ssgay6/namespaces/firebase:fetch?key=AIzaSsdUkWBGtkIGsauWl2nT6aood1g18ieOyUY HTTP/1.1 
Host: firebaseremoteconfig.googleapis.com 
Content-Type:  application/json 
Connection: close 
X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier: zzkko.com.ZZKKO 
If-None-Match: etag-353013613329-firebase-fetch-2005478008 
Accept: */*
Content-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: en-us 
Content-Length: 371
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate User-Agent: dsaj/2.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0
```

is that `key= parameter` should be secret ? or it should be public?

what attacker can do if he finds out the API key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you setup firebase in an iOS app (seems to be the same for Android too), you have to [download a configuration file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#add-config-file) from your Firebase account and add that to your application.

It contains other IDs including `CLIENT_ID` and `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID`.

As far as I'm aware you would need to have this configuration file to be able to use the `API_KEY`

[image]